# index.html file is the only styled document when uploaded to a server using FileZilla

Tags: html, css

Hello I am very new to coding so I will try my best to explain my issue as clear as possible. I have recently completed my personal page using HTML and linking in to a single stylesheet document. After uploading all the files consisting out of 6 HTML pages, one CSS style sheet and one image folder all located in one folder, all HTML files were no longer styled except for the index.html file. I have tried everything from changing the link, relinking the CSS to the HTML documents, re-uploading the files, checking file permission, etc. When opened locally all HTML documents worked but once uploaded only the index file is styled while all the other documents revert back to their basic form. Here some of the code to help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  <!-- The actual CSS style sheet -->
</head>
<div id='nav'>
     <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
          <li><a href="About_Me.html">About Me</a></li> 
          <li><a href="Contact_me.html">Contact me</a></li>
          <li><a href="Education.html">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="Languages.html">Languages</a></li>
          <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<!-- All six documents start with this code -->
```

The link used to access the page ends with https://www.ucl.ac.uk/.../Final_Project/index.html
The dots are not the actual link but just filler so the link is not published and accessed by random people.

Comment: You could try specifying an absolute URL for the stylesheet. I.e. instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />` you could try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/.../Final_Project/style1.css" />`?

Comment: @NicholasByfleet That did not seem to work thanks for the help though I will keep trying to figure it out. I went into inspect mode and found out that the stylesheet is not linked with the other documents however when opened locally it is so I am going to look into that more.